# jQuery mobile - Ajax-driven navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to develop a Phonegap (1.3) app on Android (2.1) with jQuery Mobile (1.0).

I am using an example from an book (Pro jQuery Mobile) and it works on Firefox, but not on Google Chrome or inside the android emulator and I would like to know why this doesn't work.

The code of the first page ("index.html") is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hijax Example</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<!-- First Page -->
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Hijax Page</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="contact.html" data-role="button">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code of the second page ("contact.html") is:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">    
        Contact information
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is the "Error loading page" from jQuery.

Comment: looks like path issue did you try with http:// protocol to defining a path of contact.html ?

Comment: +1 It's not going to work for file:// protocol in Chrome (but will work in Firefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now on Android emulator. The reason it didn't work was that I included a wrong version of Phonegap. I forgot that phonegap-1.3.0.js is platform dependend and we included the version for Windows Phone and not for Android.

Unfortunately it still doesn't work on Chrome.